# Python use dictionary to replace variables in a string

Tags: python, string, dictionary, replace

Similar questions out there, but not quite my use case. I would like to use a dictionary reference to replace variables within a string. In this case, the string is a sql statement, but not too relevant.

SQL with variables {}-

```
qry = """SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN {{cols_1}} is null AND {{cols_2}} > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS output
    FROM mytable"""
```

dictionary -

```
dict = {'cols_1': 'id', 'cols_2': 'weather'}
```

So then it would end up like this -

```
qry = """SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN id is null AND weather > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS output
    FROM mytable"""
```

And I'd like to replace cols_1 and cols_2 with dictionary values. But I'm not sure how to do this?

```
def substitute_values(qry, dict):

    if dict:
        qry = qry.replace('{{cols_1}}','{{cols_2}}'),dict[]
    
    return qry
```

After spinning my wheels a bit, appreciate any guidance.

Comment: You should probably be using a prepared statement here rather than trying to bind and concatenate the statement yourself.  What is your SQL version?

Comment: ok i would like to try this approach but appreciate alternatives. postgresql

Comment: Have you ever heard of SQL injection vulnerabilities? You're in serious danger of creating one.

Comment: i'm only trying to create a reference to a column value in the effort of automation

Comment: Why are you using two brackets like that? `{{cols_1}}`? Is this supposed to be a jinja template??

Comment: this is a string within a jupyter notebook that I'd like to automate variables before being read into sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
qry = """SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN {{cols_1}} is null AND {{cols_2}} > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS output
    FROM mytable"""

d = {'cols_1': 'id', 'cols_2': 'weather'}


for k,v in d.items():
    qry = qry.replace('{{'+k+'}}', v)
    
print(qry)
```

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN id is null AND weather > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS output
    FROM mytable
```

Comment: this is what i'm looking for but i'm running into an error ```'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'```

Comment: are you defining the dictionary as `d` instead of `dict`? try to not use `dict` as variable name. Also, is your `qry` a string or a tuple? Try running the whole code i have provided first to test if it works. then see if you are providing `qry` in the same form.

Comment: ok this will work for me, but i am a newbie so would like to understand what the issue/"danger" of doing this approach is?

Comment: Do read this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: I see the documentation has a hefty warning, but I'm still not quite understanding .. Can someone explain a bit more what issue of replacing {{ }} variables is ?

Comment: If someone (with malicious intent) passes a keyword that you unknowingly replace and run your query, they can cause serious damage to your database. Example, someone sends the string "1=1" which is always True as a condition, instead of a valid condition. This will cause them to get full read access to the database.

Comment: but unless they have access to my notebook, how would they do so?

Comment: They wont, its just not a good practice to use code like this.

Comment: i see, so better practice to not use {{ }} and use $ instead?

Comment: No thats not the point. both are equally bad. Basically replacing any string from another input variable (which maybe input by another user) in a SQL query is bad practice. $ or {{}} doesnt matter. The $ is only for the specific library called Template. It doesnt protect againt potential SQL injections.

Comment: Since you are doing all of this on your local and just for automation of your work, i dont think its an issue, but either way, doing any of this is a bad practice in production.

Comment: ah ok i see, thank you for explaining. yes this won't be going to production, just for local automation purposes

Comment: Exactly, be very careful where you take the dictionary from. Thats the point.

Comment: Do mark the answer if it helped you and do upvote it if it’s well written to your liking. This encourages me to help solve your future questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Template. Easy:

```
from string import Template
qry = """SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN $cols_1 is null AND $cols_2 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS output FROM mytable"""
dict = {'cols_1': 'id', 'cols_2': 'weather'}
qry = Template(qry).safe_substitute(dict)
```

Documentation here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings

Comment: ELI5 , why is $cols_1 much better than {{cols_1}}? still learning

Comment: This is what supported by Template library. From documentation:
"Template strings support $-based substitutions, using the following rules:"

Comment: Still it is doable using Template to put {{}} instead of $. But then it will be very complex as you have to create your own Templating Class. Furthermore, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360603/python-template-safe-substitution-with-the-custom-double-braces-format

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.format` twice:

```
print(qry.format().format(**d))
```

Output:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN id is null AND weather > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS output
    FROM mytable
```

Comment: What are the dangers to this?